# Capitalize no date "n.d." in in-text citation with apacite style

Tags: bibtex, citing, apa-style

Is there a way to capitalize the "n.d." or no date in in-text citation in LaTeX? As in:

```
Lorem ipsum (Doe, n.d.) to Lorem Ipsum (Doe, N.D.)
```

Or for the sake of it is there a way to customize "n.d." to something else?

I am using APA citation style for BibTeX:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

Sample reference with no date:

```
@misc{Git,
  author = {Git},
  title = {Git: the fast version control system},
  howpublished = {Retrieved November 11, 2011, from CVS: \url{"http://git-scm.com/"}}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the `apacite` package, you need to alter the `\bibnodate` command. This seems to be set at the start of the document, so use the `\AtBeginDocument` hook:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Git,
  author = {Git},
  title = {Git: the fast version control system},
  howpublished = {Retrieved November 11, 2011, from CVS: \url{"http://git-scm.com/"}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\bibnodate}{N.D.\hbox{}}%
}
\begin{document}
\cite{Git}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```